# 10-faces dice "emulation" from N 6-faces dices

Tags: probability, simulation, dice

I want to play a game which uses one 10-faces dice, but I only have 6-faces "classic" dices at my disposal.

Is it possible to approximately recover, to an arbitrary precision, a 10-faces dice probability distribution using N classic 6-faces dices and clever algorithm ?

I have no clue how or even if this is remotely possible.

Thanks you in advance for your kind help.